# Erro ao gravar um Arquivo em um Vetor

Tags: c

Aparentemente segue tudo certo na gravação dentro do while, botei um printf para testar, mas após o laço, não imprimi mais os itens do vetor, e não consegui encontrar o erro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct date
{
    char nome[15];
    int tam;
} date;
int main(void)
{
    FILE *arq;
    date dados[5];
    int i=0;
    arq = fopen("App.txt", "r");
    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while( (fscanf(arq, "%s %d\n", dados[i].nome, &dados[i].tam)) != EOF )
        {
            printf("%s %d \n", dados[i].nome, dados[i].tam);
            i++;
        }

    }

    printf("%s %d \n", dados[0].nome, dados[0].tam); //Nao imprimi

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Caso algum moderador veja essa pergunta, queria falar sobre negativarem minha pergunta sem explicação, e sendo que expliquei minha dúvida, e deixei o código certo, não é a primeira vez que isso acontece '-'

Comment: Sugiro que pergunte algo mais especifico, e não um código inteiro esperando uma correção, de mais detalhes, quando recebemos um código inteiro como esse seu, muitas vezes nem sabemos o contexto desse código, por isso os usuários negativam sua pergunta. Agora sobre a pergunta.

Comment: Note que seu programa só funcionará corretamente se seu arquivo tiver no máximo 5 registros, já que você não testa se extrapolou a quantidade máxima definida para o array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parâmetro que você usou no seu open esta errado, você abriu o arquivo apenas para leitura.

```
arq = fopen("App.txt", "r");
```

Se você precisa abrir o arquivo para leitura e gravação terá que usar algum desses modos descritos na imagem, escolha o que atende melhor ao seu problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas do vetor eu só vou ler o que tem nele, e passar pro vetor, não vou alterar nada dentro dele não

Comment: Seu código está funcionando perfeitamente, se ainda tiver problema, atualize o post com o erro retornado pelo seu compilador, assim fica mais fácil lhe ajudar.